# Use of "Would" instead of "Will"

Tags: grammar

Could someone explain me why we should use "Would" in this sentence instead of "will"?

> "April 1, 2014, the day which I ***would*** never forget in my life as Microsoft has awarded me with the Most Valuable Profession Award (MVP) for my Excelling skills".

Comment: Because while the speaker has terrific Excel skills, their Spoken-English skills need some serious work. (or, they are a native of India)

Comment: Do you mean that "would" is wrongly used here?

Comment: @Oldbag: I'm not aware that IE has any particular tendency to mix past/present perfect] *(would/has [awarded])* in this way.

Comment: @santhosha - I can't say for sure... as I'm unable to tell which tense they are shooting for.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - My IE extrapolation was not based on the mix of tenses, per se, but the generally rambling(?) construction of the statement and the excessive qualifying. (It sure weren't no Yankee, what said it like that.)

Comment: @Oldbag: oic. Yeah - I originally thought ***Excelling** skills* was just "whimsical", but looking at the text as a whole, you're probably right. Definitely NNS, since native speakers would be unlikely to mistakenly use *Profession* there even if they didn't already know the abbreviation stood for *Most Valuable **Professional***.

Answer (score -3):

To begin with, "would" is a past continuous tense. That means that this person who wrote the phrase *would* never forget, or to rephrase *had never forgotten.*
However, "will" is referring to "in the future", so will is not the correct word to use. The sentence is fine as is.

Comment: "would" is not past continuous tense.